# Use function argument as object key in Mongoose Update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but I must have read a 100 questions by now, but I still haven't been able to figure this out.

I have a function that takes four aguments: `senderId`, `field`, `content` and `response` in a node module. The function itself runs a [Mongoose Model Update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) to update the specified field with the supplied content. Code below:

```
module.exports = function(senderId, field, content, response) {

    var errorMessage = "Sorry, I'm having problems processing your request. Please try again later.";

    cemForm.update({ "senderId" : senderId }, {
        field : content
    }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            fb.textOnlyMessage(senderId, errorMessage);
        } else {
            fb.sendButtonMessage(senderId, response);
        }
    });
};
```

If I use this function like so:

```
cemUpdate(event.sender.id, "issueType", cemQuestions.issue.buttons[0].title, cemQuestions.voiceSpecificIssue);
```

The code executes perfectly and I get the correct response, however, the database is not updated. If I replace the object key `field` with its contents (`issueType`), the database updates appropriately. I've tried logging the variable, and I'm 100% certain that it is a string and it is `issueType`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you can't reference a field using a variable. To get round it do something like....

```
module.exports = function(senderId, field, content, response) {

    var errorMessage = "Sorry, I'm having problems processing your request. Please try again later.";

    var updateObj = {};
    updateobj[field] = content;

    cemForm.update({ "senderId" : senderId }, updateObj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            fb.textOnlyMessage(senderId, errorMessage);
        } else {
            fb.sendButtonMessage(senderId, response);
        }
    });
};
```

Untested, but hopefully should work.

FYI: Here's a simple example without Mongo etc [here](http://jsbin.com/vifujixeve/edit?js,console)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can use [computed property keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
module.exports = function(senderId, field, content, response) {

    var errorMessage = "Sorry, I'm having problems processing your request. Please try again later.";

    cemForm.update({ "senderId" : senderId }, {
        [field] : content
    }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            fb.textOnlyMessage(senderId, errorMessage);
        } else {
            fb.sendButtonMessage(senderId, response);
        }
    });
};
```